# backbone events not triggering off method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Backbone events are still bound after the event execution, object.off is not executing after the trigger

pfb the abstract of code

```
var object = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

object.off('app:test:load', function() {
    console.log("========my foot=======");
}, this);
object.on('app:test:load', function () {
    //fn calls
});

object.trigger('app:test:load');
```

All thoughts are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with this code as it is presented:

- *off* method is called *before* function is registered, so it is understandable, that trigger will invoke log or other call
- anonymous function is passed to *on*. Anonymous functions can be only removed with different override of *off* function
- *this* is passed into *off*, for code written in such way, *this* will point to parent object (might be even window), so code will actually try to remove callbacks from some other thing, not *object*

Working example which might shed some light on this issue:

```
// create object which support events
var object = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

// define function as non-anonymous
var doAction = function () {
     console.log("========my foot=======");
};

// function has to be registered first (cannot remove something that is not there)
object.on('app:test:load', doAction);

// register another function to illustarate removal of anonymous functions
object.on('app:test:load', function(){
    console.log("from anonymous");
});

// will invoke both functions
object.trigger('app:test:load');

// example 1: only remove this particular function for this particular trugger
object.off('app:test:load', doAction);

// will invoke only anonymous, since first one was removed
object.trigger('app:test:load');

// example 2: only remove ALL registered functions for this trigger
object.off('app:test:load');

// will not write anything
object.trigger('app:test:load');
```

Comment: I know this is an old one, but curious, can you do `.on('app:test:load',myFunc(var1))` and `.on('app:test:load',myFunc(var1,var2))` and then only remove the one with one parameter? `.off('app:test:load',myFunc(var1)` or does that only work on *differently named* functions. What about `.off('app:test:load',myFunc` would that remove both?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about **zombie objects** which are explained in this Derick Bailey-a post

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/09/15/zombies-run-managing-page-transitions-in-backbone-apps/

That means that there is a reference to some portion of your code, which is not removed by off method.